# Array to String Conversion error on passing multi-dimential array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, arrays, curl, php-curl

Hope you are doing really great.
I want to pass the multi-dimential as `raw-data` to my cURL request. But When I try to pass the array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` it gives me an error for Array to String Conversion.

When I am trying to pass the array like:

```
    $post_data = [
        "date"=> $_POST['date'],
        "items" => $plan_details,
        "form" => [
            "clientName" => [
                "name"      => $_POST['form_data'][0]['clientName'],
                "mobile"    => $_POST['form_data'][0]['mobile'],
            ],
            "clientAddress" => [
                "line"      => $_POST['form_data'][0]['addressLine'],
                "city"      => $_POST['form_data'][0]['addressCity'],
                "state"     => $_POST['form_data'][0]['addressState'],
                "country"   => "",
                "pincode"   => ""
            ],
            "clientGST" => [
                "companyName"   => "",
                "gstNo"         => ""
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

And the cURL request:

```
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "<URL>",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post_data,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer <key>"
        ),
    ));
```

How can I pass the Multi-Dimential Array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?

Comment: what POST formats does the target API support? does it support `multipart/form-data` ? does it support `x-www-form-urlencoded` ? does it support `application/json` ?

Comment: Thank you @hanshenrik. The catch was `Content-Type: application/json`. I have kept it in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`  and it works fine now.

Comment: the code you provided above won't work with an API requiring application/json, you would need ```CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($post_data),``` for that

Comment: Correct. I just forgot to mention that. We need to `json_encode` the data and then provide the `Content-type`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `http_build_query` function to build postfields string.

Comment: Thank you for your help @pavel-třupek but the API server was not accepting the string we built with the `http_build_query` so the passing of the `Content-type` in headers worked for me.

Comment: I thought you want to encode array into post data parameters, not json encoded.